# HuggingFace | ValueError: Connection error, and we cannot find the requested files in the cached path. Please try again or make sure your Internet con

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, huggingface-transformers, valueerror, gpt-2

Not always, but occasionally when running my code this error appears.

At first, I doubted it was a connectivity issue but to do with cashing issue, as discussed on an older [Git Issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/8690).

Clearing cache didn't help runtime:

```sh
$ rm ~/.cache/huggingface/transformers/ *
```

Traceback references:

- NLTK also gets `Error loading stopwords: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known`.
- Last 2 lines re `cached_path` and `get_from_cache`.

---

Cache (before cleared):

```sh
$ cd ~/.cache/huggingface/transformers/
(sdg) me@PF2DCSXD:~/.cache/huggingface/transformers$ ls
16a2f78023c8dc511294f0c97b5e10fde3ef9889ad6d11ffaa2a00714e73926e.cf2d0ecb83b6df91b3dbb53f1d1e4c311578bfd3aa0e04934215a49bf9898df0
16a2f78023c8dc511294f0c97b5e10fde3ef9889ad6d11ffaa2a00714e73926e.cf2d0ecb83b6df91b3dbb53f1d1e4c311578bfd3aa0e04934215a49bf9898df0.json
16a2f78023c8dc511294f0c97b5e10fde3ef9889ad6d11ffaa2a00714e73926e.cf2d0ecb83b6df91b3dbb53f1d1e4c311578bfd3aa0e04934215a49bf9898df0.lock
4029f7287fbd5fa400024f6bbfcfeae9c5f7906ea97afcaaa6348ab7c6a9f351.723d8eaff3b27ece543e768287eefb59290362b8ca3b1c18a759ad391dca295a.h5
4029f7287fbd5fa400024f6bbfcfeae9c5f7906ea97afcaaa6348ab7c6a9f351.723d8eaff3b27ece543e768287eefb59290362b8ca3b1c18a759ad391dca295a.h5.json
4029f7287fbd5fa400024f6bbfcfeae9c5f7906ea97afcaaa6348ab7c6a9f351.723d8eaff3b27ece543e768287eefb59290362b8ca3b1c18a759ad391dca295a.h5.lock
684fe667923972fb57f6b4dcb61a3c92763ad89882f3da5da9866baf14f2d60f.c7ed1f96aac49e745788faa77ba0a26a392643a50bb388b9c04ff469e555241f
684fe667923972fb57f6b4dcb61a3c92763ad89882f3da5da9866baf14f2d60f.c7ed1f96aac49e745788faa77ba0a26a392643a50bb388b9c04ff469e555241f.json
684fe667923972fb57f6b4dcb61a3c92763ad89882f3da5da9866baf14f2d60f.c7ed1f96aac49e745788faa77ba0a26a392643a50bb388b9c04ff469e555241f.lock
c0c761a63004025aeadd530c4c27b860ec4ecbe8a00531233de21d865a402598.5d12962c5ee615a4c803841266e9c3be9a691a924f72d395d3a6c6c81157788b
c0c761a63004025aeadd530c4c27b860ec4ecbe8a00531233de21d865a402598.5d12962c5ee615a4c803841266e9c3be9a691a924f72d395d3a6c6c81157788b.json
c0c761a63004025aeadd530c4c27b860ec4ecbe8a00531233de21d865a402598.5d12962c5ee615a4c803841266e9c3be9a691a924f72d395d3a6c6c81157788b.lock
fc674cd6907b4c9e933cb42d67662436b89fa9540a1f40d7c919d0109289ad01.7d2e0efa5ca20cef4fb199382111e9d3ad96fd77b849e1d4bed13a66e1336f51
fc674cd6907b4c9e933cb42d67662436b89fa9540a1f40d7c919d0109289ad01.7d2e0efa5ca20cef4fb199382111e9d3ad96fd77b849e1d4bed13a66e1336f51.json
fc674cd6907b4c9e933cb42d67662436b89fa9540a1f40d7c919d0109289ad01.7d2e0efa5ca20cef4fb199382111e9d3ad96fd77b849e1d4bed13a66e1336f51.lock
```

Code:

```py
from transformers import pipeline, set_seed

generator = pipeline('text-generation', model='gpt2')  # Error
set_seed(42)
```

Traceback:

```
2022-03-03 10:18:06.803989: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-03-03 10:18:06.804057: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
[nltk_data] Error loading stopwords: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or
[nltk_data]     service not known>
2022-03-03 10:18:09.216627: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-03-03 10:18:09.216700: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:269] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2022-03-03 10:18:09.216751: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (PF2DCSXD): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2022-03-03 10:18:09.217158: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-03-03 10:18:09.235409: W tensorflow/python/util/util.cc:368] Sets are not currently considered sequences, but this may change in the future, so consider avoiding using them.
All model checkpoint layers were used when initializing TFGPT2LMHeadModel.

All the layers of TFGPT2LMHeadModel were initialized from the model checkpoint at gpt2.
If your task is similar to the task the model of the checkpoint was trained on, you can already use TFGPT2LMHeadModel for predictions without further training.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/project/foo/bar/__main__.py", line 26, in <module>
    nlp_setup()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/project/foo/bar/utils/Modeling.py", line 37, in nlp_setup
    generator = pipeline('text-generation', model='gpt2')
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/__init__.py", line 590, in pipeline
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/tokenization_auto.py", line 463, in from_pretrained
    tokenizer_config = get_tokenizer_config(pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/tokenization_auto.py", line 324, in get_tokenizer_config
    resolved_config_file = get_file_from_repo(
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/file_utils.py", line 2235, in get_file_from_repo
    resolved_file = cached_path(
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/file_utils.py", line 1846, in cached_path
    output_path = get_from_cache(
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/sdg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/file_utils.py", line 2102, in get_from_cache
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Connection error, and we cannot find the requested files in the cached path. Please try again or make sure your Internet connection is on.
```

---

**Failed Attempts**

1. I closed my IDE and bash terminal. Ran `wsl.exe --shutdown` in PowerShell. Relaunched IDE and bash terminal with same error.
2. Disconnecting/ different VPN.
3. Clear cache `$ rm ~/.cache/huggingface/transformers/ *`.

Comment: Assuming you are running your code in the same environment, transformers use the saved cache for later use. It saves the cache for most items under `~/.cache/huggingface/` and you delete related folder & files or all of them there though I don't suggest the latter as it will affect all of the cache causing you to re-download/cache everything.

Comment: Ahhh, hold on. I mightn't have PyTorch installed in my `conda venv`

Comment: I fixed the issue by disabling firewall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am working in a **conda venv** and using **Poetry** for handling dependencies, I needed to re-**install torch** - a dependency for Hugging Face  Transformers.

---

First, install torch:
[PyTorch's website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) lets you chose your exact setup/ specification for install. In my case, the command was

```bash
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```

Then add to Poetry:

```
poetry add torch
```

Both take ages to process. Runtime was back to normal :)

Answer (score 3):

I saw a answer in github which you can have a try:

pass **force_download=True** to **from_pretrained** which will override the cache and re-download the files.

Link at :https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/8690 By:patil-suraj

Answer (score 1):

make sure you are not loading a tokenizer with an empty path. That solved it for me.

Comment: Awesome to know there's another solution for a different reason for the error occurring. Ty for contributing

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, faced this issue with a custom docker image when trying to deploy to Azure AKS.

The docker image was built with a docker commit on a docker container that already had all the files in the cache. I was expecting nothing to go to the internet during deployment (access is restricted) since the cache is prepopulated, but it failed with the error message:

```
ValueError: Connection error, and we cannot find the requested files in the cached path. Please try again or make sure your Internet connection is on.
```

It required these two environment variables to be set in the container:

```
TRANSFORMERS_OFFLINE=1
PYTORCH_TRANSFORMERS_CACHE=/home/app_user/.cache/huggingface/transformers
```

the first one instructing it to not go to internet to download the files and the second one being the path to the cache, which has the downloaded huggingface files.

Answer (score 0):

This command nearly kill me

```html
$ rm ~/.cache/huggingface/transformers/ *

(torch2.0.0_cu11.8) (base)  ✘ zanzhuheng@asus  ~/Desktop/Working   main ±  rm ~/.cache/huggingface/transformers/ *
zsh: sure you want to delete all 16 files in /home/zanzhuheng/Desktop/Working [yn]? y
rm: cannot remove '/home/zanzhuheng/.cache/huggingface/transformers/': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'birds': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove 'breast': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove 'breast_ckpt': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove 'Child_Mind': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove 'convnext': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove 'ESCA': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove 'home': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove 'leaves': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove 'Multi_Stain_Deep_Learning_Nature_Medicine_2023': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove 'rmb': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove 'rsna_breast_cancer': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove 'to_the_MICCAI': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove 'UBC_Ovarian_Cancer': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove 'wandb': Is a directory
(torch2.0.0_cu11.8) (base)  ✘ zanzhuheng@asus  ~/Desktop/Working   main ±  
(torch2.0.0_cu11.8) (base)  ✘ zanzhuheng@asus  ~/Desktop/Working   main ±  rm ~/.cache/huggingface/transformers/ *
zsh: sure you want to delete all 14 files in /home/zanzhuheng/Desktop/Working [yn]? n
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).